# Multi Condition Index Match Formula Retune Last Match with Array formula in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

on K4 =ArrayFormula(INDEX($E$4:$F,MATCH(1,1/(H4=$B$4:$B)*(I4=$C$4:$C),3)*(I4=$D$4:$D),3)))

This formula retune exact last row entry in match condition, but I want to use array formula  for retune all rows entry.

[image]

Comment: What's "all rows entry"? Please use [minimal, viable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you have 1) clearly defined input, and 2) clearly defined desired output. If your input/output are more than very atomic elements, please include an example sheet so the answerers don't have to recreate yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to retrieve the most recent match to the input "item" in the H column of the table B3:F.

in Cell I4 past the formula `=IF(H4="",,INDEX(FILTER($C$4:$F,$B$4:$B=H4),COUNTA(INDEX(FILTER($C$4:$F,$B$4:$B=H4),,1)),))` and drag down all the way to the bottom.

you can copy [this sheets.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3M6jEOskxsAok5a4GSAhAmGDLtq41gx2IMMcui1V6g/edit?usp=sharing) directly.
[image: See this image]

I hope I successfully solved your question.